# How to resolve the conflict between libncurses5-dev:i386 and libncurses5-dev:x64?

Tags: android, build, kernel

I use Ubuntu 12.04-x64 as the Android development environment.
But now I met a conflict between libncurses5-dev:i386 and libncurses5-dev:x64:
The build for Android system needs an i386 version libncurses5-dev. But the menuconfig for kernel needs a x86 version libncurses5-dev.
How can I resolve it? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try solution from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-building/nS_iGRot90s)
The idea is to install libncurses5-dev and then install lib32ncurses5-dev. This has worked for me.